# Plotting large map into several smaller A4

Tags: qgis, printing, atlas, plot, paper

I am using QGIS. I have a big map and licence for exploration. How can I split map with layer bounds (red line polygon-licence) in a few A4 which one will continue to another one etc. in scale 1:5000?

Comment: you should have a look  to QGIS Atlas function: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the map? This could help in giving specific answer. Also as suggested  by @eurojam look into atlas generation. Here is another example of creating [atlas](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be common but need some steps to be done with QGIS. Here is one of the method to do it. It is based on the process used in the atlas documentation but updated as function used have been updated in QGIS.

1. Open Processing > Toolbox > Vector Creation > Create grid
2. A modal will open and you should choose as **gird type** : `rectangle (polygon)`,
3. as **grid extent** your area of interest based on a layer or drawn in the canvas.
4. And set the Vertical spacing and Horizontal spacing based  on the size in map unit you want your maps to be.
5. Run the algorithm. Save the produced layer.
6. Use the produced layer as atlas coverage layer in your layout and hide it.

You may need to do several try to get what you want, with the correct overlay between pages and the right scale.